# Currency fetch does not work anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this code in my applicaton which is used to get a xml list of current rates from web and save them for future use in the app.

```
def get_rates
  today_path = Rails.root.join 'rates', "#{Date.today.to_s}.xml"

  Hash[Hash.from_xml(if File.exists? today_path
                       File.read today_path
                     else
                       xml = Net::HTTP.get URI 'http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml'
                       File.write today_path, xml
                       xml
                     end)["Envelope"]["Cube"]["Cube"]["Cube"].map &:values]
  end
```

This was written like half a year ago.
Now since today, it does not work anymore. I get this error:

```
NameError in FormController#converter
uninitialized constant FormController::Net
```

What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `net/http` library is not being required. It may have been required somewhere else in your application and that line was deleted or a gem could have been removed that loaded the library which allowed it to work. Try adding the following line at the top of your file before the class definition and see if it works again.

```
require "net/http"
```

Comment: Yep ,had it in my routes before, did not remember why it was there and deleted it...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to do `require 'net/http'`. Add that line in your form_controller.rb file and try to run that method again to check if it works.